# Calling an external jQuery function from php File

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to use Messi.js to return a pop up box if the user has an input error in a form. I have a php file called add email:

```
<?php
/ini_set('display_errors',1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
//error_reporting(-1);

include('connectionFile.php');   
//test for duplicate emails
$query="SELECT * FROM ClientEmail WHERE ClientEmailAddress = '" . $_POST['emailAdd'] . "'";
$email=$_POST['emailAdd'];
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num==0)
{
if(isset($_POST['emailAdd']) && $_POST['emailAdd'] != "<<please enter email>>" && $_POST['emailAdd'] !="")
{
// the form was submitted
//remove hacker HTML
$email=strip_tags($_POST['emailAdd']);

//Insert data into database
$sql2="INSERT INTO ClientEmail SET ClientEmailAddress='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql2);

}
else
{
print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'new Messi("Please enter a valid email.", {title: "Input error", modal:true});'; 
print '</script>';

}
}
else
{

print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'new Messi("Sorry, you have entered an existing email.", {title: "Duplicate Email", modal:true});'; 
print '</script>';
}
?>
```

I am not sure where to call the jQuery files and css. I have done so in my index.php page(where the addEmail function is called) but it is still not working.

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Club Blaque - Sign up for the Revolution</title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/messi.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"  type="text/javascript"/>
        <script src="js/messi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT

My form section currently looks as follows

```
   <form name="emailAddr" method="post" action="">
        <p>BE INVITED TO THE REVOLUTION <input id="emailAddress" name="emailAdd" type="text" value="<<please enter email>>" onFocus="clearText(this)" onblur="addText(this)"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><img id="submitImage"src='image/submit.ico'/></button> </p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Where is the include with the jquery and messi in the PHP you posted? It has to be available to the script

Comment: when I include the .js files, my webpage outputs a long string containing the contents of the files

Comment: @user2624044 Please see my answer below for details re where to place code in your .PHP or .HTML page. I updated answer to also respond to your comment just above.

Comment: Thanks gibberish, I have uploaded the code for my form as i had used a button as opposed to an input. In addition I feel I will still need validation in the addEmail.php as I am querying the database

Comment: @user2624044 The key thing with the button is don't make it `type="submit"`, or else you'll have to do backflips to stop the form from submitting if there's a problem: `e.preventDefault()`. Instead, make it like the button I used: `type="button"`. Also, there's no good reason to use `<button>Button Text</button>` instead of `<input type="button" value="Button Text" />`. Same appearance to user. ------ For querying the database, use AJAX. I will update my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the field validation testing in jQuery/javascript before even POSTing the form. That way you can trap errors without refreshing the page.

Note how the Submit button is `type="button"`, not `type="submit"`. The submit function is done via jQuery.

See below stand-alone, fully working example.
[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EmVLQ)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    //Do your field validation testing here, then submit if okay
                    var em = $('#emailAdd').val();
                    var pw = $('#pwordAdd').val();
                    if (em !='' && pw !='' ) {
                        $('#myform').submit();
                    }else{
                        alert('Please complete all fields');
                    }
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<form id="myform" action="yourphpprocessor.php" method="POST">
    Email Address:<br />
    <input id="emailAdd" name="emailAdd" type="text" /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input id="pwordAdd" name="pwordAdd" type="password" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Submit It" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Note that if you wish to store the javascript/jQuery in an external file the code would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='myjavascript.js'></script>
```

And the file `myjavascript.js` would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mybutt').click(function() {
        //Do your field validation testing here, then submit if okay
        var em = $('#emailAdd').val();
        var pw = $('#pwordAdd').val();
        if (em !='' && pw !='' ) {
            $('#myform').submit();
        }else{
            alert('Please complete all fields');
        }
    });

}); //END $(document).ready()
```

---

For querying the database during field validation, use AJAX. It allows you to send the email address off to a PHP file (let's call it your PHP processor file), do the database lookup, and return a response. The response is anything that you want to build: from a simple 1 or 0 response, to a fully formatted HTML response that you will post into a DIV. In your case, a simple 1 or 0 will be fine.

First thing you must decide is how you want to trigger the AJAX lookup. You could use *Submit* button, but in our example let's use the jQuery `blur()` selector as it is triggered the moment a user leaves a field.

```
$('#emailAdd').blur(function() {
    //Test if this email already exists
    var em = $('#emailAdd').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpprocessor.php",
        data: 'eml='+em+'&anothervar='+summatelse,
        success: function(whatigot) {
            alert(whatigot);
            if (whatigot == 'itexists') {
                alert('This email address already exists. Please choose another.');
                $('#emailAdd').css({'background-color':'yellow','border-color':'red'});
                $('#emailAdd').focus();
            }
        } //END success callback
    }); //END ajax block
}); //END emailAdd.blur
```

An Important Note About AJAX: All processing of received info **must happen in the `success:` function**. So, for example, the error message must happen in there. Once you start working with AJAX (95% of which is in this example - it's not very difficult), this note must be your Bible. Remember it.

Your PHP processor file would look like this:

**myphpprocessor.php**

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['eml']; //Note that it is same as the var NAME posted in AJAX
    $summat = $_POST['anothervar'];

    if ($email != '' && $email != '<<please enter email>>') {
        include('connectionFile.php');   
        //test for duplicate emails
        $query="SELECT * FROM `ClientEmail` WHERE `ClientEmailAddress` = '$email'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($num > 0) {
            echo 'itexists';
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```